# Meaning of the phrase "you guys" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

It is from [Crash Course Film History](https://youtu.be/opQC45irmN8). It is at 6 minute and 15 second.

> Ticket sales were falling, and studio executives were in an outright panic. Studio executives like money, **you guys**.

Comment: I’m pretty sure that it’s referring to the viewers of the video.

Comment: But why did he say it? What is the meaning of it?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, realize that 'you guys' is often used informally in English to refer to groups of people regardless of the gender composition of the group.

For this case:

"You guys" refers to the audience. Putting it at the end of a sentence is used for emphasis, comedic effect, or to illustrate that the point being made (studio execs like money) is an incredibly obvious and straight-forward concept. It emphasizes the idea that all execs care about is the money and implies that everyone is aware of this.

You might also see y'all in its place.  For example if you are talking to a group about your vacation.

"So we turn around and see a bunch of elephants stampeding towards us. I probably don't need to say this, but elephants are BIG, y'all (you guys). "

Comment: Does it mean the same as the phrase "you know"?